# How to remove &#65279; extra character in my Website?

Tags: html, joomla

I see this character in Firebug `&#65279;`.

I don't know why this is happening, there's no such character in my code. For Firefox it's OK, but in IE everything breaks. I can't even search for this character in Google.

I saved my file with utf-8 encoding without bom.

[image]

Comment: It is a [zero width no break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm).

Comment: for what it's worth, one possible reason for it breaking things in IE is if the character is being output at the start of the file before the doctype. If that's happening then IE will treat the doctype as invalid and flip the page into quirks mode.

Answer (score 6):

This occurs when you include files that contains the char ﻿ (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE).

this character is a BOM and you can only see BOMs with low level text editors (such as DOS edit).

you can debug it seeing the Element inspector, and commenting the requires or includes to see what file contains the BOM.

then , you can copy the content of the file, change the Encoding to "encode in utf8", save and you can include it again. (notepad++) can save it

success.

Comment: `&#xFEFF` - I fixed this by opening the page in notepad, and save as with UTF-8 instead of UTF-8 with BOM.  resolved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`&#65279;` is probably a UTF-8 byte order mark in one of the files Joomla uses or includes (it's only a zero-width no break space if it occurs inside a file).

You could try [this tool](http://www.bryntyounce.com/filebomdetector.htm) to check for byte order marks - they're a bit of a pain to search for by hand.

Comment: Probably there are *two* BOMs at the start of the file. The first one is good, but the second one is then taken as a data character. It then implicitly opens the `body` element (because `head` cannot contain data characters except whitespace), causing the document to be misparsed (as the screen shot shows: `head` is empty, and `meta` appears inside `body`).

Comment: Joomla files should never have  BOM. Someone may have saved a file in notepad or similar and gotten one.  You have to use an editor that does not insert these.

Answer (score 1):

just save again your php file with notepad++

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.

I opened the file with notepad and saved it as UTF8.
problem solved.