# How to fix displacement on the page from top

Tags: php, html, css, smarty

During the work on moving the page from PHP 5.3 to PHP 7.1 there was a problem with the appearance of the site.
The page is moved from the top by 17-18 pixels.
I can not find a reason. I want the page to look like before.

Please help.

On website there is a PHP 7.1
before was 5.6

screenshot how it was before (ok) and after (bad)

```
<body>
    <div id="container">    
        <div id="header">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Gminny.Osrodek.Kultury.w.Babimoscie" title="" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEU4r.jpg" alt="Jesteśmy na Facebook" title="" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="mainnav">
            <div class="nav-container-outer">
                <ul id="nav-container" class="nav-container">
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How to Back  to previous appearance

Comment: You have exactly this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584820/how-to-remove-65279-extra-character-in-my-website

Comment: Hmm, well, besides the characters, you've placed almost everything that should be in `<head>` within `<body>`...